# Symmetric and asymmetric graphs

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, group-actions, automorphism-group

Let $\Gamma = (V, E)$ be a self-complementary graph with $|V| \geq 2$, how do i prove that exists $\sigma \in S_{V}$ such that:

I. $xy \in E$ if and only if $\sigma(x)\sigma(y) \notin E$.

II. $\sigma^{2} \in$ Aut $\Gamma$, but $\sigma^{2} \neq 1$.

III. The orbits of $\sigma$ induce self-complementary subgraphs of $\Gamma$.

I know some basic results about self-complementary graphs, such as, their order is congruent to $1$ or $0$ mod $4$, any self-complementary graph is connected, the group of automorphisms of a graph is the same as that of its complement.

Comment: How far did you get? Can you prove that there is a permutation $\sigma$ which satisfies condition I?

Comment: Do you know the *definition* of self-complementary graphs? Isn't it that there is a graph isomorphism between the graph and its complement?

Comment: A graph $\Gamma = (V, E)$ is self-complementary if $\Gamma$ is isomorphic to its complement, then there exists a bijection $\varphi: V \longrightarrow V$ such that $uv \in E$ if and only if $\varphi(u)\varphi(v) \notin E$.
$\varphi$ is a permutation that satisfies condition one, since $\Gamma$ and $\Gamma^{c}$ share the same set of vertices V. I have observed with examples that $\varphi^{2}$ is an automorphism of $\Gamma$ and that it is different from the identity permutation. Now I'm looking at how to prove that indeed $\varphi^{2} \in $ Aut $\Gamma$ and that $\varphi^{2} \neq 1$.

Comment: $uv\in E\iff\varphi(u)\varphi(v)\notin E\iff\varphi^2(u)\varphi^2(v)\in E$

Comment: To show that $\varphi^2$ is not the identity permutation, show that the permutation $\varphi$ has at most one fixed point, and that it has no cycles of length $2$.